# Executing a function as a parameter when passed to an arrow function - ES6

Tags: three.js, ecmascript-6

I'm making use of the `3.js` library and am at the stage of actually rendering the object/shape to the screen, which renders like this:

[image: Cube]

In the [tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/ajeetyadav/8uTD9/) that I'm making use of it has some code for rotating the cube on it's x and y axis:

```
cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
```

This works if I add it to the render function like so:

```
var render = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
  cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
  this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
};
```

But I want to be flexible in the animation approach and pass any rotations or whatever as a function to be executed inside the render function. I've tried to do this:

```
var render = (animation) => {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  animation();
  this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
};
render(this.animation(cube));
```

What I can see this that the code is executed **once** correctly as a function but each subsequent time it then say's that it isn't a function.

What am I missing here and how can I ensure that this is executed as a function each and every time?

Thanks

**EDIT**

From Engineer and sdgluck's answer this is what I think they mean but it still didn't work:

```
var render = (animation) => {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  animation();
  this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
};
render(() => this.animation(cube));
```

**EDIT 2**

This is all the code in the service that creates the cube and attempts to animate it:

```
export class ThreeService {

    constructor() {
        this.scene;
        this.aspect;
        this.camera;
        this.renderer;
    }

    /*
        Creates the scene, the camera and the renderer
    */
    setup() {
        this.createScene();
        this.createCamera();
        this.createRenderer();
    }

    createScene() {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    }

    createCamera() {
        // This is the viewpoint that the users are looking from
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1,10000);
    }

    createRenderer() {
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.getElementById('model').appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
    }

    createCube() {
        // Creates the basic structure of the cube
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(700, 700, 700, 10, 10, 10);

        // Adds colour to the cube using materials
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xfffff, wireframe: true});

        // Cubes needs a geometry and a material to be rendered
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        this.addObjToScene(cube);
        this.positionCamera(1000);

        var render = (animation) => {
            debugger
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            animation();
            this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
      };
      render(() => {this.animation(cube)});
    }

    animation(obj) {
        obj.rotation.x += 0.01;
        obj.rotation.y += 0.01;
    }

    addObjToScene(obj) {
        // They then needed added to the scene
        if(!this.scene) 
            this.setup();
        // By default the add function adds the obj to the coordinates 0,0,0
        this.scene.add(obj);
    }

    positionCamera(zPos) {
        if(!this.camera)
            this.setup();
        this.camera.position.z = zPos;
    }

    rotateObj(obj,x,y) {
        obj.rotation.x += x;
        obj.rotation.y += y;
    }

}
```

And this is the error code that is appearing:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: animation is not a function
browser_adapter.js:84EXCEPTION: TypeError: animation is not a functionBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:84
browser_adapter.js:84STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:84
browser_adapter.js:84TypeError: animation is not a function
    at render (three.service.js:49)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:44)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:355)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:256)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:423)
BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:84
Subscriber.js:229
Uncaught TypeError: animation is not a function
```

Comment: Are you calling `render` the same way each time? Can you provide more context (code) around your call to render, or is this all you have?

Comment: @sdgluck this is all I have

Answer (score 2):

I guess `this.animation(cube)` does not return a function which you expect to call inside of render (by `animation();`). Possible workaround could be:

```
render(() => {
    this.animation(cube);
});
```

Comment: Or just `render(() => this.animation(cube));`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. From what I understand from your answer you would place this inside the parameters when you call the render function and then call animation in the actual function? See my edit

Comment: @Katana24 Pls, provide actual code of your animation function. Also do you get any errors? Pls provide those too.

Answer (score 0):

@Engineer provides a solution, but doesn't explain that the reason your shared example does not work as you expect is that **you are calling `this.animation` in place**, not passing reference to the function or a function that wraps it (as in @Engineer's answer).